# How to write a variadic function without parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

suppose I have a template

```
template<typename Bar>
Result foo(const Input& input);
```

and I instead want to create a template `foo()` that would get many `Bar` template arguments and many `Input`'s and put the `Result` together.

I wrote a version with a container of inputs:

```
template<typename Bar>
Result foo(const std::vector<Input>& inputs);

template<typename Bar1, typename Bar2, typename ... Bars>
Result foo(const std::vector<Input>& inputs) {
    // calls foo<Bar2, Bars ...>(shorter_inputs);
}
```

However, the version above cannot check at compile time if the length of the input matches the number of template arguments. Also, I want a version that would simply take the inputs, without the need for a container:

```
foo<Bar1, Bar2>(input1, input2);
// instead of
// foo<Bar1, Bar2>({input1, input2});
```

My attempts to write something like this

```
template<typename Bar1, typename Bar2, typename ... Bars>
Result bar(const Input& in1, const Input& in2, const Input& ... inputs)
```

were rejected by the compiler, because `...` only works with a parameter pack. Is it possible to write such a variadic function in C++, without resorting to `va_args`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use two parameter packs:

```
template<typename Bar, typename... Bars, typename Input, typename... Inputs>
std::string foo(const Input &input, const Inputs &... inputs)
{
    std::string result(Bar::get_name());
    result.append(input);

    if constexpr (sizeof...(inputs) > 0)
        result.append(foo<Bars...>(inputs...));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, but when I try to recurse the template, the expanded Inputs become the Bars. Do you have any links to an example that I could, well, copy?

Comment: To keep it simple let's just assume that each Bar class has a static std::string get_name() method, and foo concatenates the names, inserting some string delimiters (the Inputs) between them.

Comment: @user44168, I've updated the example with a body based on what you provided in your question. However it uses a C++17 `if constexpr` feature to end the recursion. Can you use C++17 or you can only use C++11?

Comment: @user44168, updated again with a string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the solution! My mistake was expanding both packs as <Bars..., Inputs...>. The project is in C++14, so I ended the recursion with a separate definition of bar<typename Bar, typename Arg>.

Comment: C++ is strange like this. Instead of letting the author specify that the type of the inputs should be Input (like std::string for my example), the problem of using correct types is left for the caller of the template.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what do you want...

If `Result` and `Input` are types and not template parameters and you want a template `foo()` that receive as many `Input` objects a template parameters, you can start from a custom template parameter `GetFirst` to select the first template parameter in a variadic list

```
template <typename T0, typename ...>
struct GetFirst
 { using type = T0; };
```

and write `foo()` as follows

```
template <typename ... Bars>
Result foo (typename GetFirst<Input, Bars>::type const & ... is)
 { 
   // something with is...
   return {};
 }
```

So you have

```
//foo<long, long long>(Input{}, Input{}, Input{}); // compilation error

foo<int, long, long long>(Input{}, Input{}, Input{}); // compiles

//foo<int, long, long long>(Input{}, Input{}); // compilation error
```

If you want to manage the single `is...` recursively, you can write `foo()` as follows

```
template <typename, typename ... Bars>
Result foo (Input const & i0,
            typename GetFirst<Input, Bars>::type const & ... is)
 {
   // do something with i0

   return foo<Bars...>(is...);
 }
```

but you need also a ground case template `foo()` to terminate the recursion; I propose a `foo()` that receive a template not-type parameter with a default value (to intercept the `Bars...` when the list is empty)

```
template <int = 0>
Result foo ()
 { return {}; }
```

The following is a full, maybe silly, but compiling example

```
struct Input  { };
struct Result { };

template <typename T0, typename ...>
struct GetFirst
 { using type = T0; };

// ground case
template <int = 0>
Result foo ()
 { return {}; }

// recursive case
template <typename, typename ... Bars>
Result foo (Input const & i0,
            typename GetFirst<Input, Bars>::type const & ... is)
 {
   // do something with i0

   return foo<Bars...>(is...);
 }

int main()
 {
   //foo<long, long long>(Input{}, Input{}, Input{}); // compilation error

   foo<int, long, long long>(Input{}, Input{}, Input{}); // compiles

   //foo<int, long, long long>(Input{}, Input{}); // compilation error
 }
```